# Averaging watershed areas

Tags: hydrology, water

If I am looking at different USGS stream gages, calculating their 90th percentile streamflow, and then doing a weighted average of the 90th percentile of the streamflows using the watershed areas - what average watershed area represents this estimate?  The normal arithmetic mean?  Or some other mean?

Comment: I don't have a definitive reference but it makes sense to me to use the arithmetic mean because you are in essence normalizing to the precipitation across the area. That is what you would use in calculating a water balance.